# c# convert ninject specific bindings to autofac

Tags: c#, ninject, autofac

I have two problems on converting bindings from ninject to autofac.

The first is:

```
Bind<IMapper>().ToConstant(new Container().Mapper);
```

and the second is:

```
Bind<Context>().ToSelf()
               .WithConstructorArgument(CONNECTION_STRING, 
               c => c.Kernel.Get<IUserDatabase>().ConnectionString)
```

May you lend me a hand?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one:

```cs
builder
    .RegisterInstance(new Container().Mapper)
    .As<IMapper>();
```

For the second one:

```cs
// First option, with a parameter
builder
    .RegisterType<Context>()
    .AsSelf()
    .WithParameter(
        (parameter, context) => parameter.Name == CONNECTION_STRING,
        (parameter, context) => context.Resolve<IUserDatabase>().ConnectionString));

// Second option, with a lambda
builder
    .Register(x => new Context(x.Resolve<IUserDatabase>().ConnectionString))
    .AsSelf();
```

I prefer the second option as you get static checks on the constructor of your `Context` class, but it can be a pain to maintain if you have lots of parameters.

I'd suggest reading the article linked from [this tweet](https://twitter.com/arialdomartini/status/811467422427398144). It talks about how using primitives as constructor parameters makes our lives harder and how to work around it.

Comment: `.AsSelf()` is optional, as it's a default behavior, if you do not have any registartions by interfaces.

Comment: Just amazing. Perfect. Thank you guys.